# canceling email send with asp.net custom validator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, email

I have a form that sends an email that includes 4 fields.  One of the fields is validated by a custom validator against the database and if the value is found the email should send.  If it is not found the email should cancel and there should be an error message.  Everything is working except the email sends regardless of the validation.  How can I keep the email from sending?

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class inforequest
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)



    Dim mm As New MailMessage("sender@email.com", "receiver@email.com")
    mm.Subject = txtSubject.Text
    mm.Body = "Name: " & txtName.Text & "<br /><br />Email: " & txtEmail.Text & "<br />" &                       txtBody.Text & "<br /> Agent Code:" & AgentCode.Text


    mm.IsBodyHtml = True
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
    smtp.Host = "mailserver"
    smtp.EnableSsl = False

    Dim NetworkCred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential()
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False


    NetworkCred.UserName = "username"
    NetworkCred.Password = "password"
    smtp.EnableSsl = False

    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred
    smtp.Port = 587
    smtp.Send(mm)
    lblMessage.Text = "Email Sent SucessFully."
End Sub






Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    Dim dbconn As String
    Dim qstring = Request.QueryString("ID")
    Dim addressDR As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

    Dim sqlcommand As String = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE ID=@qstring"
    dbconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("houses").ToString

    Dim connection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(dbconn)
    connection.Open()
    Dim addresscmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlcommand, connection)
    addresscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qstring", qstring)

    addressDR = addresscmd.ExecuteReader()





    If addressDR.HasRows Then
        addressDR.Read()
        Me.txtBody.Text = "I would like to request a showing of the home located at: " & addressDR("address") & " MLS#: " & addressDR("mlsnum")
        addressDR.Close()


    End If

    connection.Close()





End Sub




Protected Sub CodeValidate_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CodeValidate.ServerValidate

    Dim AgentCode = Request.Form("AgentCode")
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT agentcode FROM Codes WHERE agentcode = @AgentCode"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Codes").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgentCode", AgentCode)

            conn.Open()
            Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If (rdr.Read()) Then
                    'MsgBox("reader reading")
                    'If AgentCode = rdr("agentcode").ToString() Then
                    args.IsValid = True

                    'MsgBox("valid!")
                Else
                    args.IsValid = False

                    'MsgBox("not valid")
                End If

            End Using
            conn.Close()

        End Using

    End Using
End Sub




End Class
```

Comment: Nevermind, I got it.  I declared a boolean and set to true in the validator and then only send if its set to true.  I was overthinking

Answer (score 2):

You need to call Page.Validate() and also check Page.IsValid